# Need to grab character before the dash and 2 characters after a dash in variable length string in pl/sql

Tags: oracle, plsqldeveloper

I have string that looks like these: K-07 ADC080715, SCRAPPED BY JOE 0-09. I am looking to extract the character before the dash and the 2 characters after the dash. Everything I've tried researching explains how to grab everything before or after a character, not a specific length before or after. I am using pl/sql.

Answer (score 2):

```
with data as
( select 'K-07 ADC080715' val from dual )
select substr(val,instr(val,'-')-1,1) v1,
       substr(val,instr(val,'-')+1,2) v2
from data
```